# JPanel repainting only when scrolling

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jpanel, repaint

I have a JPanel inside of a JScrollPane. I have added a number of JButtons in a column in the JPanel and this works great; I can scroll down with ease and press any button I want.
When pressing a button I want to change the contents of the JPanel. Let's say I want to replace the JButtons with a new set of JButtons.

This is how I do (simplified):

```
private void replace(String[] newButtonNames){
        panel.removeAll();      //Removing all old buttons from my JPanel
        JButton button;
        for(int i=0; i<newButtonNames.length; i++){
            button = new JButton(newButtonNames[i]);  //Create a new button
            panel.add(button);   //Add the button to the panel
        }
        panel.repaint();   //Repainting it so that the results show up
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that the "repaint" method only seems to remove the old buttons leaving me with a blank JPanel. However, the second I scroll the new buttons appear instantly so it seems like the JPanel simply doesn't repaint properly.

I tried searching for this but didn't get anything. If you know an answer, please tell me (if you know another post here that has the same question, with an answer, then a link there would be greatly appreciated too)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

By default component have a size/location of (0, 0) until you invoke the layout manager. So there is nothing to paint.

The general code for removing/adding components to a panel is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

You would only do the revalidate() and repaint() after all the updates have been done to the panel so you only invoke the layout manager once.